# pandas dataframe query not working with where

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas, I have this data frame:

`df['educ1']`

which gives

```
1        4
2        3
3        3
4        4
5        1
        ..
28461    3
28462    2
28463    3
28464    2
28465    4
Name: educ1, Length: 28465, dtype: int64
```

when I try querying with

```
dt=df[df.educ1 > 1]
```

It's working fine returning multiple rows, but when I try

```
college_grad_mask=(df.educ1 > 1)
df.where(college_grad_mask).dropna().head()
```

It gives 0 rows, I wonder what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have NaNs in many columns, try to subset:

```
df.where(college_grad_mask).dropna(subset=['educ1']).head()
```

Or better:

```
df[college_grad_mask].head()
```

Comment: clear thank you, is there a reason why the second is better?

Comment: It's shorter and should be more efficient, you have nothing to recompute